# Cannot convert string due to None Error

Tags: python, type-conversion, nonetype

```
def draw_constellation_file(file_name):
  x = open(file_name)
  y = x.read()
  y = y.splitlines()
  for i in range(0, len(y)):
      a = y[i]
      b = a.split(',')
      aa = str(get_line_for_star_name(b[0]))
      cc = get_star_point_from_line(aa)
      return aa
```

`get_star_point_from_line` looks like this:

```
def get_star_point_from_line(stardata):
  stardata = stardata.split(',')
  x = float(stardata[0])
  y = float(stardata[1])
  return [x, y]
```

The output:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: None

Here's the thing: the `stardata.split` doesn't seem to split. I'm sure it has something to do with the `None`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide sample data that causes the error?

Comment: That for loop is pointless. An unconditional return inside a for loop?

Comment: have you tried to check the value of `stardate` before it split?

Comment: It may pain you to type the extra characters, but using meaningful variable names instead of random single or double letters will go _a long way_ toward improving the readability of your code.

Answer (score -1):

"None" tends to indicate that nothing is being passed into the function in question. You should make sure that the data you're passing in is what you expect it to be.

In this case, `stardata[0]` or `stardata[1]` might not exist. That being said, you need to check the line number to know which one is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It seems there is an error with this code

```
def get_star_point_from_line(stardata):
  stardata = stardata.split(',')
  x = float(stardata[0]) //passing string value in float will cause an error
  y = float(stardata[1]) 
  return [x, y]
```

I think the data from the parameter `stardata` has contained a string value.

Comment: **-0.581457,-0.294806,0.758286,120315,1.85,5191,BENETNASCH**  This is what goes in for stardata. The split function doesnt convert it for whatver reason and the float breaks.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of setting the cc = get_star_point_from_line() with the value of aa try to set y value since aa has already splitted, and do not inclue cc = get_star_point_from_line(y) in for loop.

Answer (score -1):

You're passing `aa = str(get_line_for_star_name(b[0]))` 
into `get_star_point_from_line(stardata):` and that shows you only passing 1 index: b[0].

If b[0] is not a full list and only one string than when you assign `x = float(stardata[0])`and`y = float(stardata[1])` you are trying to assign those variables to indices that dont exist.

If b[0] is a full string it may be splitting up differently than what you thought it would. I would try splitting it using just `split()` instead of `split(',')` and then `rstrip(',')` to get rid of the commas.

Its difficult to pinpoint the problem without knowing what the list looks like when you originally did `aa = str(get_line_for_star_name(b[0]))`. Which by the way is converting that into a string, which you then attempt to reconvert later into a float, which I thought was kind of odd.

Answer (score -1):

in draw_constellation_file, you set b = a.split(',') and pass b[0] to get_line_for_star_name, b[0] will have no ',', so may be you can post the code for get_line_for_star_name to see the reason for the probelm